# R's grepl in Julia

Tags: julia, grepl

I am not trying to reinvent the wheel. Just looking for a function which searches a string or string vector and returns true for each element where the match is found. This is what I tried so far.

```
grepl(x::String, y)         = length(search(x, y))   > 0
grepl(x::Vector{String}, y) = length.(search(x, y)) .> 0
grepl(x::Vector{AbstractString}, y) = length.(search(x, y)) .> 0
```

Example usage:

```
v = string.('a':'z')
x = rand(v, 100) .* rand(v, 100) .* rand(v, 100)
grepl(convert(Vector{String}, x), "z")
```

Well, this would be a working example if I could get my types to work properly. Basically I could use the return to select only elements which have `"z"` in them.

Comment: Could you give a quick example desired input/output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [`contains`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/strings/?highlight=contains#Base.contains).  On 0.6, you can use it directly with dot-broadcasting:

```
julia> contains.(["foo","bar","baz"],"ba")
3-element BitArray{1}:
 false
  true
  true
```

On 0.5, you can simply wrap the second argument in an array: `contains.(["foo","bar","baz"],["ba"])`.

Comment: I sometimes struggle to remember if `contains(x, a)` is `x` contains `a` or vice versa. In that case using `a ⊆ x` is clearer to me. The equivalent of the above code is then `"ba" .⊆ ["foo", "bar", "baz"]`. It does not call the same code, but rather `issubset`, but the performance seems identical.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment. `issubset` is not equal to `contains`. For example, `"ba" ⊆ "abc"` returns `true`.